# Does anyone know the OS distro, editor and how is he spliting screens?

Tags: linux, archlinux

If you look at http://bambuser.com/v/2846316 you can see a developer with two monitors, in the video this person is spliting the screens into multiple outputs of an editor. And switching the content of them... Does anyone know how to do something like this ? Or the editor he/she is using ? I think the distro is Archlinux and the website on the movie is http://japh.se

**EDIT:** Ahhhhh found it. Depends on the type of the Windows Managers ! :D I was looking for Tiling windows managers :D

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_manager

Could anyone recommend me one ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) to me, which is very nice for that and is my windows manager on arch linux. You can also have a look at [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) which is quite equivalent but older.

For the editor its not clear for me since I dont see him use it so I cant distinguish between vim and emacs.

Comment: Just edited my question hehe... Thank you, Im looking awesome website atm :)

Comment: if you are on arch linux this is your next step: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Awesome :)